# display multiple data in session variable

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

In my application i m retrive data from database. In database contain 10 records. but when i am display record in page it display only one record. i want all 10 record neeeds to be display. i m using session variable to store and display data in page . i dont want any control to bind data. i want only session variable to be used to store and display data . below i m write code. i know session store only one value but i want session store multiple value and display multiple data.

.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Aarambh;Initial Catalog=rebuild_technology;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from content_managment ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)

        {
            Session["divhtml_heading1"] = dr["divhtml_content"].ToString();

        }
}
```

Here i am display data in aspx page.

**Source code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <% Response.Write(Session["divhtml_heading1"].ToString()); %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What this `dr["divhtml_content"]` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to store all database contents in Custom object like

```
List<string> lstOfDivHtml = new List<string>();
```

Store contents in it in foreach loop like

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
    lstOfDivHtml.Add(dr["divhtml_content"].ToString());
 }
```

You populate lstOfDivHtml in the forloop & then set it in session once after the for loop like

```
Session["divhtml_heading1"] = lstOfDivHtml
```

And when you display the contents on page, retrieve lstofDivHtml from Session & display it in loop

```
var list = Session["divhtml_heading1"] as List<string>; // now loop over 'list'.
```

P.S.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Define list
        List<string> lstOfDivHtml = new List<string>();  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Aarambh;Initial Catalog=rebuild_technology;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from content_managment ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
          //add records from dr to lstOfDivHtml 
          lstOfDivHtml.Add(dr["divhtml_content"].ToString());
        }
  }
```

On Page markup or codebehind

```
<% 
var list = Session["divhtml_heading1"] as List<string>;
foreach(var item in  list )
{
 Response.Write(item); 
}
%>
```

Cant be more specific than this now :)

Comment: but it not display data it showing me System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] as output

Comment: You need to cast the session var to a list and then loop over that: var list = Session["divhtml_heading1"] as List<string>; // now loop over 'list'.

Comment: Thanks Buddy its great logic ,

Answer (score 0):

Quick an dirty way would be to use:

```
Session["divhtml_heading1"] &= dr["divhtml_content"].ToString();
```

to **append** row data, instead of:

```
Session["divhtml_heading1"] = dr["divhtml_content"].ToString();
```

which **replaces** row data.